# Codeigniter - HTMLPurifier Configuration

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce, xss, htmlpurifier

I am using Codeigniter framework for developing a site. We are having tinyMCE plugin to enter HTML text which is required in some places. Everything is working fine, but we are trying to prevent XSS from the HTML text input. We should sanitize the post data, which can accept only html, but not javascript. Right now we are using the following way to take post data without sanitizing.

```
Utils::array_value('company_website', $data)
```

Then after I came to know about [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org). I am not able to configure it in Codeigniter. I am trying this code in a Builder function :

```
require_once '../../libraries/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

It is throwing an error in error log:

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../../libraries/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/internshala/application/My_App/Helpers/My_Builder.php on line 52, referer: http://local.mylocal.com/my_controller/my_method

Comment: Where did you place `require_once '../../libraries/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';` i mean the path ?

Comment: In `My_Builder.php` which is a Helper contain common functions required by most of the controllers.

Comment: When you say helper i guess its inside `helper` folder

Comment: @Deepak HTMLPurifier library is in libraries folder of codeigniter.

Comment: Yes, It is in helper folder only.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter provides a constant `APPPATH`, which is the location of the `application` folder, defined in `index.php`.

Using that, you can do

```
require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
```

which should be a more foolproof method of requiring the file.